# Copy data from one table #1 into table #2 then remove the remaining rows of table # 2 for particular Sales Invoice ID

Tags: sql-server

Sorry to say i have not in depth knowledge of SQL queries. I have to modify an existing application that records and maintain the customers installments payments.

For this purpose I have a requirement in which i want to copy date of 
`TableNo1` into `TableNo2` except `New_Amount`(TableNo1) column data, and then remove the remaining rows of `TableNo2` for each `SalesInvoiceID`.

Actually `TablNo1` has modified installment payment plan and that is why it is required to modify `TableNo2` accordingly.

**TableNo1**

```
New_ID   SalesInvoiceID   InsttNo   DueDate      New_Amount     
1           30             1        2019-05-02     12000            
2           30             2        2019-06-02     12000            
3           30             3        2019-09-02     4000         
4           30             4        2019-12-02     4000
```

**TableNo2**

```
Instt_ID   SalesInvoiceID   InsttNo   DueDate   PaymentDate   Amount    Status
51              30            1     2019-05-02      NULL       0        Up-Coming
52              30            2     2019-06-02      NULL       0        Up-Coming
53              30            3     2019-07-02      NULL       0        Up-Coming
54              30            4     2019-08-02      NULL       0        Up-Coming
55              30            5     2019-09-02      NULL       0        Up-Coming
56              30            6     2019-10-02      NULL       0        Up-Coming
57              30            7     2019-11-02      NULL       0        Up-Coming
58              30            8     2019-12-02      NULL       0        Up-Coming
```

**Required Output (TableNo2)**

```
Instt_ID   SalesInvoiceID   InsttNo   DueDate   PaymentDate   Amount    Status
51            30             1       2019-05-02     NULL        0       Up-Coming
52            30             2       2019-06-02     NULL        0       Up-Coming
53            30             3       2019-09-02     NULL        0       Up-Coming
54            30             4       2019-12-02     NULL        0       Up-Coming
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Do you want to `INSERT` or `UPDATE` existing rows in TableNo2? Because here's what I am understanding. You want to UPDATE TableNo2 with the DueDate and Amount fields from TableNo1 (matching on Instt_ID). Then DELETE the rows from TableNo2 that don't exist in TableNo1.

Comment: The output schema is labelled `TableNo1`, but the schema matches `TableNo2`. I think we need a bit more detail here about what you're trying accomplish.

Comment: I want to UPDATE TableNo2 with  only DueDate from TableNo1 matching on SalesInvoiceID.Then DELETE the rows from TableNo2 that don't exist in TableNo1

Comment: @Eric Brandt Sorry i have updated the required table schema name which is TableNo2

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: As i mentioned above "I want to UPDATE TableNo2 with only DueDate from TableNo1 matching on SalesInvoiceID.Then DELETE the rows from TableNo2 that don't exist in TableNo1 "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm guessing at the relationship between the tables correctly, this should be all you need, but before you delete any production data you should test this on copies of the tables.

```
UPDATE t2
  SET t2.DueDate = t1.DueDate
FROM
  dbo.TableNo2 AS t2
  JOIN
  dbo.TableNo1 AS t1
    ON t1.SalesInvoiceID = t2.SalesInvoiceID
    AND t1.InsttNo = t2.InsttNo;

DELETE t2
FROM 
  dbo.TableNo2 AS t2
WHERE 
  NOT EXISTS
    (
      SELECT 1 
      FROM dbo.TableNo1 AS t1
      WHERE t1.SalesInvoiceID = t2.SalesInvoiceID
      AND  t1.InsttNo = t2.InsttNo
    );
```

Comment: How to do it for a particular SalesInvoiceID e.g  SalesInvoiceID =30 so that it does not effect others data related to others SalesInvoices

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1 (New_ID INT IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,SalesInvoiceID 
INT,InsttNo INT,PaymentDate DATE,New_Amount INT )
CREATE TABLE #Table2 (New_ID INT IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,Instt_ID INT, 
SalesInvoiceID INT,InsttNo INT,DueDate DATE,PaymentDate DATE,Amount INT,Status 
VARCHAR(20))


INSERT INTO #Table1  (SalesInvoiceID,InsttNo,PaymentDate,New_Amount) VALUES (30 
,1,'2019-05-02','12000')
INSERT INTO #Table1  (SalesInvoiceID,InsttNo,PaymentDate,New_Amount) VALUES (30 
,2,'2019-06-02','12000')
INSERT INTO #Table1  (SalesInvoiceID,InsttNo,PaymentDate,New_Amount) VALUES (30 
,3,'2019-09-02','4000')
INSERT INTO #Table1  (SalesInvoiceID,InsttNo,PaymentDate,New_Amount) VALUES (30 
,4,'2019-12-02','4000')


INSERT INTO #Table2 
(Instt_ID,SalesInvoiceID,InsttNo,DueDate,PaymentDate,Amount,Status) VALUES 
(51,30,1,'2019-05-02',NULL,0,'Up-Coming')
INSERT INTO #Table2 
(Instt_ID,SalesInvoiceID,InsttNo,DueDate,PaymentDate,Amount,Status) VALUES 
(52,30,2,'2019-06-02',NULL,0,'Up-Coming')
INSERT INTO #Table2 
(Instt_ID,SalesInvoiceID,InsttNo,DueDate,PaymentDate,Amount,Status) VALUES 
(53,30,3,'2019-07-02',NULL,0,'Up-Coming')
INSERT INTO #Table2 
(Instt_ID,SalesInvoiceID,InsttNo,DueDate,PaymentDate,Amount,Status) VALUES 
(54,30,4,'2019-08-02',NULL,0,'Up-Coming')
INSERT INTO #Table2 
(Instt_ID,SalesInvoiceID,InsttNo,DueDate,PaymentDate,Amount,Status) VALUES 
(55,30,5,'2019-09-02',NULL,0,'Up-Coming')
INSERT INTO #Table2 
(Instt_ID,SalesInvoiceID,InsttNo,DueDate,PaymentDate,Amount,Status) VALUES 
(56,30,6,'2019-10-02',NULL,0,'Up-Coming')
INSERT INTO #Table2 
(Instt_ID,SalesInvoiceID,InsttNo,DueDate,PaymentDate,Amount,Status) VALUES 
(57,30,7,'2019-11-02',NULL,0,'Up-Coming')
INSERT INTO #Table2 
(Instt_ID,SalesInvoiceID,InsttNo,DueDate,PaymentDate,Amount,Status) VALUES 
(58,30,8,'2019-12-02',NULL,0,'Up-Coming')



SELECT 
 T2.Instt_ID
,T1.SalesInvoiceID
,T1.InsttNo
,T1.PaymentDate DueDate
,T2.PaymentDate
,T2.Amount
,T2.Status 
 FROM #Table1 t1
 INNER JOIN #Table2 T2 ON t1.New_ID = t2.New_ID

 DROP TABLE #Table1,#Table2
```

[image]